# Mongoose error "Cannot read property 'ObjectID' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, express, mongoose

Bit of a n00b to node.js and mongodb. When I try to set up a project with mongodb and mongoose I keep getting an error after requiring the mongoose module. Not sure what is going on, wish there was a better debugger for node.

I fire up mongod and start up the app.js with node. Then I get this error.

```
/home/archie/Development/working/nodepad/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/bson/bson.js:422
 "    var options_array = [];
node.js:134
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ObjectID' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/archie/Development/working/nodepad/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/objectid.js:6:43)
at Module._compile (module.js:411:26)
at Object..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:31)
at Function._load (module.js:302:12)
at require (module.js:355:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/archie/Development/working/nodepad/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/objectid.js:12:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:411:26)
at Object..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:31)
```

This is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
var mongoose = require('mongoose') ;
   // Configuration
app.configure(function(){
 app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
 app.set('view engine', 'jade');
 app.use(express.bodyParser());
 app.use(express.methodOverride());
 app.use(app.router);
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.logger());
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.render('index', {
  title: 'Express'
 });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port,
app.settings.env);
```

any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Looks like a faulty install. Did you install mongoose via NPM? What version of node?

Comment: I installed with NPM. I uninstalled mongoose@2.3.6 and re-installed to mongoose@2.3.8, that seemed to do the trick!

Thanks!

Comment: @archieoi, can we consider it solved ?

Comment: ya I think mongoose@2.3.6 was the problem. the very least the re-installed fixed it.

Comment: Some thing I had noticed a while ago with NPM. If you remove an older version of a package, if also removes the files of the newer installed package. This might have happened to you...

Comment: Eleven years later and this is the same issue I had. uninstalled mongoose 6.3, re-installed mongoose and it updated to 7.0.3 and it works fine