# Mongoose/node error: Cannot read property 'ObjectId' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am creating a small node/express/mongo app, which allows users to post cat photos and comment on them. I have two models, `cat`, and `comment` . Everything was working fine until I decided to associate the two models together, which then caused this error:

```
type: mongoose.Schema.Type.ObjectId,
                            ^ 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ObjectId' of undefined
```

The error is referring to the cat model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var catModel = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    owner: String,  
    description: String,
    comments: [

        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Type.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment"

        } 
    ]
});

var Cat = mongoose.model("Cats", catModel);

module.exports = Cat;
```

Here is the comment model :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    username: String,
    content: String,
});


Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);

module.exports = Comment;
```

Here is a snippet of app.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
//more modules
var Comment = require('./models/comment.js');
var Cat = require('./models/cat.js');


//home route 

app.get('/cats', function(req,res) {

    Cat.find({}, function(err, cats) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);

        } else {
          res.render('cats', {cats: cats});  
        }  
    })
});
```

I am using mongoose 4.3.7 . I researched this problem and couldn't solve it. For example, I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936845/mongoose-error-cannot-read-property-objectid-of-undefined) post and re-installed mongoose, but the problem persisted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your schema the comments type but it looks quite fine but just try:

```
  comments:[{ type: String, ref: 'Comment' }],
```

or

```
  comments: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Comment"}
```

Answer (score 18):

It's a typo as there is no propery `Type` to `Schema`. It should be `Types` instead:

```
comments: [{ "type": mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, "ref": "Comment" }]
```

Comment: I had the same problem with `mongoose.Schema.types.ObjectId`, using a lowercase types.

Comment: Bless this answer . Was about to resort to banging my head on the table.

Comment: This is the thing 